# webbrowser check status in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I m using webBrowser.Navigate(uri); I want to check from the code whether the page has been loaded completely . I want to display the progress bar till the page gets loaded and once the page gets loaded I have to collapse the progress bar

I m writing an app in C# for WP7

here is what I want to do

```
          webBrowser.Navigate(uri);
          BrowserProgressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

          // If web page sucessfully loaded 
          ...............
          BrowserProgressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

          // Else throw error
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to add event handlers for the [Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigated%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and [NavigationFailed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigationfailed%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) events.  You can stop your progress bar then.